# Liquid material shading problem

Tags: modeling, volumetrics

I am beginner with blender and I'm currently trying to create some liquid (coffee for example) inside a cup. The cup is not a problem, shading of the liquid is.

I've tried to follow few tutorials on Youtube and always end up getting the same 'bug'. When I set any volume properties (volume absorption, volume scatter), these weird pixelated rectangular shapes start appearing and they flicker a lot when you rotate the view.

[image]

I've just added new material to the liquid, set the transmission to 1 and roughness to 0.01.
Then I started playing with the volume absorption and after that it starts happening.

Additional details:

- Rendering engine used is Eevee
- The more density, the more it is flickering and overlaying other objects
- It still appears if anything else besides the "liquid" itself is invisible
- It appears both in view mode and in render result

Link to project: [cup_filled.blend](http://filedropper.com/Fm8K08CG)

I'll be glad for any advices since I wasn't able to google this specific problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from Eevee render engine to Cycles, and also choose the *Rendered* viewport shading mode. Volumetrics don't work the same way in Eevee, by default it will be shaped by the cubic bounds of the object, while in Cycles it will really follow its shape.

Comment: Thank you for the info. So there is no way to work with volume using Eevee, is Cycles necessary?

Comment: Volumetrics doesn't work the same way in Eevee, you need to create an object > Volume, then give it a modifier Mesh to Volume with the liquid object as Object, then set the various parameters, but I'm not even sure you'll have a result as good as in Cycles